# Start Page not on top

Tags: css

I'd like to open my site with a div that is not on top of the page. So, something like this:

```
#div1

#div2

#the div the user sees when the page is loaded
```

(For anyone still confused, if you open any Facebook User Page on a Desktop Browser it's being loaded that way.)

My only workaround was by using JavaScript and displaying the divs above after everything is loaded. But that seems weird. There has to be another way?

Comment: Please share your current code and say what is wrong with it.

Comment: I don't think you understand what the problem is. If you have an html-file, it's always loading what is in the top of the <body>-tag. I want to start loading it at another place though. You can achieve this, by opening a page like so:

example.com/index.html#div2

But how is this possible without that "#div2" part in the url?

Comment: You would still need to show your current JavaScript code.  Saying you use one method but want another without showing the first method is a question that is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution - add `#` and the div's ID to the end of the URL. So, if your URL is `http://www.somesite.com/randompage` then to go to div number 3 you'd use the URL `http://www.somesite.com/randompage#div3`. This can be subsituted for any div in the page.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery for that!

## See it on Jsfiddle

---

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#liid").offset().top}, 1000);
});
```

---

`#liid` is the `id` of an element that you want to scroll on that!

`1000` is animation speen! you can change it

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var position=('#div').position();
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: position.top}, 500);
});
```

It will work for you